# WooCommerce Tabs not showing slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

So I have set up a WooCommerce product page. At the bottom of the page, there are the default WooCommerce tabs which I have labeled "Overview", "gallery", etc.

When I click on the gallery tab, there is shortcode on that page to display a slider using WooSlider.

The problem is that WooSlider (and most sliders in general) use the page width / height to display itself and since the gallery tab was off (content hidden), when you select it, the slider does not appear.

When you resize the browser window with the gallery tab selected, it is then able to display itself since the tab is now visible and it displays itself properly.

There are numerous posts on Google about this problem but I am having trouble implementing any of the fixes, especially because I am not so proficient with jquery (a lot of solutions require mods to the WooSlider jquery).

Can anyone with experience in this help me get this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

find

```
.wooslider.wooslider-type-posts img, body .wooslider.wooslider-type-attachments img
```

and add this style:

```
.wooslider.wooslider-type-posts img, 
body .wooslider.wooslider-type-attachments img{
height: auto; min-width: 100vw;
}
```

basically, we tell WooSlider to take the max available width of the viewport for the imagem, and then scale the height automatically

Comment: Hi Fabio - thank you for your suggestion. I have added that style to style.css in the wooslider/assets/css/ folder but unfortunately, it doesn't fix it. I left it in there if you want to see it. Do you have any other suggestions? I am using Chrome browser, if that makes any difference.

Comment: aaah, you're right, now I see it works when you click on something, no need to resize, but you need to click, and since I was testing with click states it worked fine for me. Let me think a bit and I'll see if I can find a solution

Comment: Hi Fabio - that would be great. I'm grateful for your help as I just can't figure this one out.

Comment: Fabio, did you get any other ideas about this?

Comment: ah, sorry, was trying the other day but couldn't find a solution to it